# Swift/Parse: findObjects()! changing other PFObject instances values?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've created 2 queries in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
offlineQuery = PFQuery("Dados").fromlocalDatastore()
onlineQuery = PFQuery("Dados")
```

When my app launches for the first time, my local data store is populated with online data provided by `findObject()!` method of `onlineQuery`:

```
let objects = onlineQuery.findObjects()! as! [PFObject]
PFObject.pinAll(objects)
```

When the user clicks on the refresh button I perform a search at the at my Local data store using `findObject()!` from `offlineQuery`:

```
 var objectsOff = offlineQuery.findObjects()! as! [PFObject]
```

Then I search for the online data:

```
let objectsOn = onlineQuery.findObjects()! as! [PFObject]
```

The problem starts when I try to compare both Arrays after ordering them, and the result shows that they are equal. So i decided to print the content of both, and they were truly equal.

To solve the problem I had to store their values into separated variables and then regrouped them into an Array of String. However, my code became to BIG.

What really happened here?

Comment: It's hard to say, because you're just showing some snippets. But documentation for `fromlocalDatastore()` says _Change the source of this query to all pinned objects._ And later, I see that you're pinning all objects from `onlineQuery`. That's probably the reason why both equals.

Comment: It seems to be that, but how can i save the online data at my local data store to use with my offlineQuery?